# How can I return only Firebase objects where a deeply nested property is False

Tags: python, firebase-realtime-database

If i have the following Firebase structure:

```
root:
    id1:
        subId1:
           prop: False
        subId2:
           prop: True
    id2:
        subId1:

    id3:
        subId1:
           prop: False
        subId2:
           prop: False
```

How would I return `root`, with the full tree structure, but only containing the inner-most sub-records where prop is `False`?

So i'd expect the query for the above to return:

```
root:
    id1:
        subId1:
           prop: False
```

only `root` and `prop` are known properties, the `iD` and `subId` fields are dynamically generated.

I've added an index for `prop` however the query i'm using (python) gets me no results:

```
db.reference('/root').order_by_child("prop").equal_to(False).get()
```

Comment: To get that one node, you could do `db.reference('/root').order_by_child("subId1/prop").equal_to(False).get()`. But I think you want the children on id3 too, including `id3/subId2`, which isn't possible with your current data model. See my answer below if that is indeed what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase returns full nodes from the point where you attach a listener. You can use a query to return a subset of those nodes, but each child node of the location will always be returned in full.

If you find yourself wanting to return partial nodes, consider instead changing your data model to allow the query you want. So in your case, you could create a flat list if the subnodes:

```
newRoot:
    id1_subId1:
       prop: False
    id1_subId2:
       prop: True
    id3_subId1:
       prop: False
    id3_subId2:
       prop: False
```

Now you can easily query the new root node and get only the keys with `prop: False`. Modifying your data model to allow additional use-cases like this is quite common when using NoSQL databases. To learn more I highly recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watching [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).

I also recommend checking out my answers to these related questions:

- [Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested)
- [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)